# How to specify a query parameter serializer in django-rest-swagger?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, yaml

I'm using Django REST Framework with django-rest-swagger to create browsable interface for my API. I can specify a request body serializer using [YAML docstring](http://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.org/en/latest/yaml.html), but I haven't found a way to specify a serializer for request query parameters. 
The view I am using is pretty like:

```
class ListBans(BaseBanView):

    def get(self, request):
        """
        List all profile bans
        ---
        response_serializer: backend_serializers.BanSerializer
        request_serializer: moderator_serializers.ListBansSerializer
        """
        serializer = moderator_serializers.ListBansSerializer(data=request.query_params)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            # query profile bans
            data = []
            return APIResponse(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data=data)

class ListBansSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    limit = serializers.IntegerField(default=10, help_text='query limit')
    offset = serializers.IntegerField(default=0, help_text='query offset')
```

what I am trying to achieve is to make `django-rest-swagger` create form fields for query parameters from `ListBansSerializer` so that I wouldn't have  to specify the `parameters` section manually in the docstring. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've created a simple decorator that automatically appends query parameters to the docstring. The source is available at [github](https://gist.github.com/lgyanf/c1da5b1c3899105e59558ff286358ae5). Here's a usage example:

```
class ListBansSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    limit = serializers.IntegerField(default=10, help_text='query limit')
    offset = serializers.IntegerField(default=0, help_text='query offset')


class ListBans(BaseBanView):
    @add_query_parameters(ListBansSerializer)
    def get(self, request):
        """
        List all profile bans
        ---
        response_serializer: backend_serializers.BanSerializer
        """
        serializer = moderator_serializers.ListBansSerializer(data=request.query_params)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            # query profile bans
            data = []
            return APIResponse(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data=data)
```